# Really smooth scroll mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel, smoothing

How to make a smooth scroll effect on a web page? 
Without any "steps / jerks" when we scroll the page like this website:

http://www.knoed.com/vosges-haut-chocolat-design.php

Comment: I'm afraid that's up to the operating system. Each step of the scroll wheel in windows scrolls a fixed number of lines of text, as opposed to the smooth scrolling that you get on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome extension that does that - which is written in JavaScript. You can find the source here: https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll